# Free Windows traffic monitor that can run a command when reaching a limit

Tags: windows-xp, network-traffic

Does anyone know a free traffic monitor tool for Windows XP which can run a configurable program when reaching a limit? Hoo Net Meter and DU Meter can do that, but they both cost money.

What I'm trying to do is throttle the connection when getting close to the monthly limit, so that watching YouTube or downloading large files isn't fun any longer, but e-mail or looking something up still work. The throttling part is settled, Traffic Shaper XP works nicely. I just need something to automatically call a batch script when reaching the limit.

Comment: [Check out NetBalancer](http://superuser.com/a/135751/4377)

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't seem to do what I want. I need something that can keep persistent usage records, so it survives a reboot. The best NetBalancer seems to be able to do is limit downloads while it's running, but I couldn't get even that to work.